# How to return id after insert SQL query [SQL]

Tags: php, sql

I've this SQL query and I want to get back the id after the data was insert.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO locals (owner,latitude, longitude, json_local) VALUES ('$owner','$latitude','$longitude','$json') RETURNING id";
```

How can I do this?

Here's my new function:

```
      function createLocal($owner,$latitude,$longitude,$json) {
      try {

  $sql = "INSERT INTO locals (owner,latitude, longitude, json_local) VALUES ('$owner','$latitude','$longitude','$json')";

  $sth = $this->conn->exec($sql);

  $last_id = $this->conn->lastInserId();
  echo $last_id;

  echo "New record created successfully";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  }
   $this->conn = null;
  }
```

}

But the error is: "The page doesn't work".

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I use phpmyadmin

Comment: Which one do you use mysql / mysqli / pdo etc. ? if mysql -> $lastID = mysql_insert_id();

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP, ___it is not a database___

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not a DBMS. But I guess you use MySQL then. Or MariaDB?

Comment: _Small Note_ an echo after a `return` will NEVER get executed

Comment: I use PDO ------

Comment: TYPO `return $this->conn->lastInsertId();`

Comment: It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    $LAST_INSERTED_ID = $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Try this link

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Not using `mysqli_` api

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO then you'd use [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

```
// assuming $db is your PDO object
echo $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: yes I use php PDO